# I want to build a function that has an integer input, stores its output to a global char array

Tags: c, string

0              ″___0 ″

10             ″__10 ″

999            ″_999 ″

1000           ″1000 ″

9999           ″9999 ″

10000 or more  ″**** ″

I need to know how to do this in C.
An approachable algorithm is to divide by 10. any good ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `snprintf()`?

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

something like that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(unsigned n)
{
  if (n >= 10000)
    puts("'**** '");
  else {
    char s[5];
    int ln = sprintf(s, "%u", n);

    printf("'%s%s '\n", "____" + ln, s);
  }
}

int main()
{
  f(0);
  f(10);
  f(999);
  f(9999);
  f(10000);
  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
'___0 '
'__10 '
'_999 '
'9999 '
'**** '
```

---

Or if you want to get the string rather than to just print it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* place the result in 'r' and return it */
char * f(unsigned n, char * r)
{
  if (n >= 10000)
    strcpy(r, "**** ");
  else {
    char s[5];
    int ln = sprintf(s, "%u", n);

    sprintf(r, "%s%s ", "____" + ln, s);
  }

  return r;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned v[] = { 0, 10, 999, 1000, 9999, 10000, 123456 };
  char r[6];

  for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(v) / sizeof(unsigned); ++i)
    printf("\"%s\"\n", f(v[i], r));

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
"___0 "
"__10 "
"_999 "
"1000 "
"9999 "
"**** "
"**** "
```

Comment: @chux that is a good remark, I edit my answer